# PHP send mail function

Tags: php, email, sendmail

I don't understand why my send mail function has stopped working. It used to work ok, but I've just discovered that users who try to sign up to my website no longer receive an email.

I must have changed something by accident.

I've stripped out all of the details to try and get back to basics and work out the problem. But the below code - with correct email addresses replaced - still doesn't work. It always prints that it has succeeded, but emails do not get sent to the address.

Grateful for your help!

```
$email_address2 = "my@email.com";
    $header2 = "From: webmaster@domain.org.uk\n";

    $subject2 = "Your Membership!";
    $message2 = "
    The message2
    ";

$mailsend = mail($email_address2, $subject2, $message2, $header2.">\nX-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion());

if($mailsend) {
    echo 'Your membership information has been mailed to your email address!<br/><br/>Please check it and follow the directions!';
} else {
print "There has been an error. Please try again";
}
```

Comment: Perhaps your domain/ip has been added to a black- / spamlist. Or perhaps the sendmail just isn't working any more on the machine.

Comment: Possibly. Do you know why that would happen? It has been broken for at least a week, possibly longer... I did start adding frequent domains to the cpanel blacklist as the website is coming under quite extensive spam attack... but I can't have blocked mine otherwise I presumably wouldn't be able to visit the site?

Comment: Test whether it is blacklisted at [Spamhaus](http://www.spamhaus.org/lookup/) and [MX Toolbox](http://www.mxtoolbox.com/). Also try to send a mail from the cli to see whether you get errors from sendmail.

Comment: It isn't blacklisted.... Now checking whether i get send mail errors.

Comment: How do I use the CLI? :/

Comment: E.g.: `echo test | sendmail -v your@address.com`

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to connect up the command line?.. As in, what software to use. Do I need to access this through shell - I haven't done that for ages?

Comment: My webhost has told me that I need to change the port from 25 to 26. I am learning how to.

Comment: you use echo and print. Change it to just echo

Comment: if mail() returns true, then it's handed the email off to an SMTP server successfully, so look at that server's logs. PHP's hands are washed clean of the whole thing the instant the SMTP takes the email.

Comment: Ok thanks - I guess my code is fine then. THe problem is with the SMTP server.

Answer (score 0):

The first step would be to figure out where sendmail is installed. Once you know that path, go into your php.ini. You are looking for the sendmail_path setting. Set it appropriately.

If the path is set correctly, the result from a proper call to mail() should return true. (Note that the return value only lets you know if the message was passed on to sendmail [or SMTP in the case of Windows]. It does not guarantee that the e-mail went out, or that sendmail is configured correctly.) If it is returning true and you still aren't getting e-mail, then check your sendmail configuration.